# DynamoDb with php sdk is not working

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

I am using aws php sdk and want to use dynamoDb with it.

I created an ec2 instance and install php and aws php sdk.

Now I am running this code

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

use Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\DynamoDbException;

$sdk = new Aws\Sdk([
    'endpoint'   => 'http://my_ec2_instance.com',
    'region'   => 'us-east-1c',
    'version'  => 'latest',
      'credentials' => array(
        'key'    => 'MY_KEY',
        'secret' => 'My_SECRET',
    ) 
]);
$dynamodb = $sdk->createDynamoDb();
params = [
    'TableName' => 'Movies',
    'KeySchema' => [
        [
            'AttributeName' => 'year',
            'KeyType' => 'HASH'  //Partition key
        ],
        [
            'AttributeName' => 'title',
            'KeyType' => 'RANGE'  //Sort key
        ]
    ],
    'AttributeDefinitions' => [
        [
            'AttributeName' => 'year',
            'AttributeType' => 'N'
        ],
        [
            'AttributeName' => 'title',
            'AttributeType' => 'S'
        ],

    ],
    'ProvisionedThroughput' => [
        'ReadCapacityUnits' => 10,
        'WriteCapacityUnits' => 10
    ]
];

try {
    $result = $dynamodb->createTable($params);
    echo 'Created table.  Status: ' . 
        $result['TableDescription']['TableStatus'] ."\n";

} catch (DynamoDbException $e) {
    echo "Unable to create table:\n";
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

Above example is according to aws doc and I am trying code on server not on local. When I am running above code , server become unresponsive and no table created neither any error message.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: What exactly did you mean by "server becomes unresponsive"?  What is the output of `$result['TableDescription']['TableStatus'] ` after issuing createTable request

Comment: Browser is loading , loading and loading. No error message. Just a blank page.